# Uploading Angular webapp to IBM Cloud gives 403 error

Tags: angular, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I have tried several attempt to upload app to IBM Cloud using

```
cf api "url"
cf login -u "user_id" -o BLUEMIX-SANDBOX-SJ001 -s "sandboxName"
cf push appName -b "https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack"
```

it does successfully upload and but give 403 error if viewing the url.
I even tried just creating a new HelloWorld app and upload and same result.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

- Add a “manifest.yml” file with:

`applications:
  name: my-app-name
  buildpack: staticfile_buildpack
  host: my-app-name
  memory: 32M
  path: dist`

- Run “ng build” to create “dist” folder
- Take “/dist” out of gitignore file if it exists

Comment: Thank you very much, I used 
http://cfmanigen.mybluemix.net/?cm_sp=dw-bluemix-_-nospace-_-answers&cm_mc_uid=47484863183715230405119&cm_mc_sid_50200000=77264641525399031132
to create manifest file. Followed your steps and it is solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Looking inside the dist folder, I noticed that it had the app name in it. So what worked for me is writing in manifest.yml: `path: dist/my-angular-app-name`